# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting this error and I've scoured the internet looking for a solution but none seem to work. I'm using rbenv.

```
Lachlans-MBP:~ MrTeale$ gem install rails -v 4.2.1
    Fetching: activesupport-4.2.1.gem (100%)
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Comment: You don’t have permission to write to `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0`. What is unclear? Use `sudo gem install rails -v 4.2.1` to install it globally, use `--user-install` switch to `gem` to install it for this user only, use `rvm` to make it easy to handle.

Comment: check this : https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/168